# Can't line h1 and ul

Tags: html, css

How do I make the `<h1>` element and the `<ul>` element inline?

What I have tried so far:

```css
    body{
        margin:0;
    }
    header{
        background:#999;
        color:white;
        padding:15px 15px 0px 15px;
    }
    header h1{
        margin:0;
        display: inline;
    }
    nav ul{
        margin:0;
        display: inline;
    }
    nav ul li{
        background:black;
        color:white;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px 15px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        color:white;
    }
```

```
<header>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please post all your code in the question itself. Code in external links and images are not allowed in StackOverflow. I have edited this question for you but do keep it in mind to not do it again the next time you ask a question here. Cheers.

Comment: You could add `float:left;` to the CSS with the h1, but then you'll have to re-adjust the header afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the parent element `<header>` to a flexbox using `display:flex;` like this:

```
header{
  display: flex;
  /* other css properties below */
}
```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above flexbox approach:

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  margin:0;
}
header{
  background:#999;
  color:white;
  padding:15px 15px 0px 15px;
  display: flex;
}
header h1{
  margin:0;
}
nav ul{
  margin:0;
}
nav ul li{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:5px 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<header>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```